# php-win.exe - Entry Point Not Found

Tags: php, wamp

I was trying to install PECL package in my Localhost WampServer64. After pasting all .DLL files in specific location and adding "extension=php_ssh2.dll" in php.ini as It was written in the installation steps. Check the image below.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: DId you change the version of openssl ?

Comment: Yes the last one openssl 1.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### From the Shining Light Productions Web site

*August 29, 2016 - OpenSSL 1.1.0 is quite different from previous releases. Developers need to recompile their software to support 1.1.0. See the official OpenSSL release strategy document for more details.*

What this basically means to those of us using Windows is that we have to wait until the PHP guys upgrade PHP and compile it with the new openssl 1.1.0 to be compatible with the new openssl 1.1 and its new functions and more importantly its new internal code and dll structure.

Install the latest openssl 1.0.2 release of openssl [from here](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) if you dont have another source and all should work as normal.